# Соблюдение строгого порядка свойств в обьекте

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Друзья, такой вопрос: как задать строгий порядок свойств в обьекте на js?
Проблема следующая: есть у нас, к примеру, обьект с разными свойствами:

```
let objekt = {
get arr1() {
    let a = []
    delete this.arr1
    return this.arr1 = a
},
arr2: ['bbbb'],
get arr3() {
    let a = []
    return a
},
get rows() {
    let a = this.arr1.length;
    delete this.rows
    return this.rows = a;
},
get colums() {
    let a = 0
    let property = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)
    for (var i = 0; i < property.length; i++) {
        if (property[i] === 'colums') continue
           if (Array.isArray(this[property[i]])) {
              a++
           }
        }
     delete this.colums
     return  this.colums = a;
},
obj2: {},
}

console.log(objekt)
```

Но когда я смотрю на конечный результат публикации этого обьекта, то обнаруживаю, что порядок свойств изменился:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно в данном примере, это не особо критично, но я активно использую подобные конструкции обьектов для заполнения таблиц и там порядок массивов является критически важным, если какой-то из массивов изменит свое положение в обьекте, это может сломать всю таблицу.
И теперь мне интересно, можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: Не используйте словарь если важен порядок. Используйте массив. В нём порядок гарантирован.

Comment: ты хочешь порядок в объекте или порядок при выводе? Почему ты думаешь, что порядок важен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` просто под капотом сортирует значения. Поэтому выводится так. Это нужно просто для удобства разработчика, чтобы можно быстро найти любое значение, а не в хаосе искать нужный ключ.

Eсли взять тот же `getOwnPropertyNames`, то даст нормальную последовательность... Т.е. `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objekt))` вполне себе покажет как надо

Comment: но у меня в обьекте нет целочисленных ключей, там строки, которые по идее должны гарантировать строгий порядок свойств обьекта, однако они все равно скачут из одного конца в другой... Я не понимаю, что не так... Обьекты хороши тем, что внутри них можно использовать геттеры и сеттеры, чего нельзя сделать в массивах (ну или. как минимум, я не знаю, как это делать)

Comment: @drakoblack а... я понял.... это `console.log` просто так выводит... если взять тот же `getOwnPropertyNames` то даст нормальную последовательность... Т.е. `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objekt))` вполне себе покажет как надо

Comment: @drakoblack, вывод console.log вообще не специфицирован - каждый браузер может выводить так, как хочет. а также менять способ вывода в разных версиях браузера

Answer (score 0):

Если

> порядок [...] является критически важным

то **никогда** не полагайтесь на порядок свойств в объекте.

Используйте массивы или, может быть, подойдёт `Map`. Или ещё какая-то структура которая гарантирует порядок. Но не объект.

Comment: Я тоже вначале подобный ответ написал.  А потом оказалось, что вопрос не об этом)) Точнее проблема не в том, что ТС куда-то что-то складывает

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну пусть всё равно будет. Если б автор использовал массив, то и вопроса бы такого не случилось, так что проблема автора всё ещё в неверном выборе